# Grails - How to - Unit test Service that uses params from controller

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, grails

I'm trying to unit test a service method that takes as parameters a date and the **params** LinkedHashMap from the controller. The setup is as follows:

```
def save = {CustomCommandObject erc ->
...
    if (erc.conditionProperty != null) {
        def result = myService.ServiceMethod(someDate, params)
    ...
    }
    ....
    redirect(controller: 'controllerName', action: 'actionName', id: params.id)
}

class MyService {
    static transactional = false
    ....
    def TypeToReturn ServiceMethod(Date someDate, def params){
    ...
        TypeToReturn typeToReturn = new TypeToReturn(params)
        return typeToReturn
    }
    ....
}
```

One of the tags on the GSP view is of type **< joda:timerPicker >**:

and ***TypeToReturn*** has a property:

```
LocalTime propertyName
```

When the application runs normally in the browser the params map is passed correctly to the service method and **new TypeToReturn(params)** creates an instance of ***TypeToReturn***.
params contains the following:

```
{java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry@xxxxx} propertyName_hour -> 20
{java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry@xxxxx} propertyName_minute -> 30
{java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry@xxxxx} propertyName -> struct
```

Therefore, in my test for the service method i have the following:

```
void testSomething() {
    LinkedHashMap<String, String> params = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("propertyName","struct")
    params.put("propertyName_hour", "20")
    params.put("propertyName_minutes", "30")
    myService = new MyService()
    Date d = new Date()
    myService.ServiceMethod(d,params)
}
```

**However** when i try and run the test i get the following error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: 
Cannot cast object 'struct' with class 'java.lang.String' to class
'org.joda.time.LocalTime'
```

If i ommit **params.put("propertyName","struct")** from the map completely then again it (correctly) errors saying that TypeToReturn does not have a property propertyName_hour

***How therefore, should I be unit testing such a service method that uses the params Map from the controller? Simply recreateing the map in the test doesn't seem to work. Should the params Map be mocked/stubbed in a partiular way?***

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you running your test as a unit or integration test? If it's not already there, try moving it into test/integration and run it from there using

```
grails test-app integration:
```

That runs the test within the Grails environment and will give the joda-time plugin the opportunity to do whatever meta programming magic it's doing to create the type conversion to DateTime it looks like you're missing.